# What is the earliest portrayal of cell phones as we know them now?

Tags: story-identification, history-of, computers

When I look at modern computing devices from the perspective of the nerdy kid I used to be, writing BASIC on a Vic 20, I am utterly astonished. I spent a lot of time reading Sci Fi and imagining various powerful technological advancements. But I *never* imagined anything like what we have today. I can't even think of any books I read that portrayed the way we use the Internet now.

I am quite certain this is my own ignorance, rather than an actual lack of imagination on the part of Sci Fi creators.

I know there are a lot of examples of communication devices that are close to how we use phones, but when was the first portrayal of a device that really got it right?

By "get it right" I mean the following things:

1. Ubiquitous wireless connections fast enough to stream video in real time
2. Portable devices
3. High-resolution touchscreens (or at least displays)
4. Instant communication - meaning that people expect to be able to contact someone wherever they are

Once the mainstream public actually saw computers, I think a lot of people foresaw how we use them now (my own failure to do so notwithstanding). So I think anything later than the 1970s would not qualify.

Edit: This question is pretty similar and has some good answers: [Did Science Fiction anticipate a device like a smartphone?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/93979/2352)

Comment: No.  There basically aren't any devices combining *all* these aspects that early.  Heinlein had "pocket phones" in the early 1950s, but they weren't touch-screen video-phones.  Video phones were conceived, but they were analog TV signals, not digital streaming, and mostly not portable.  Touch screens did occasionally appear, but not in the context of handheld phones.

Comment: Dick Tracy had wrist video phones, but no internet…

Comment: I know that the character Alvin, in Clarke's *Against the fall of night* (late 50's), had a wristwatch type communicator, but from what I remember its only portrayal was as a voice activated device (My only recollection was of it being used to screen calls with a self generated message along the lines of "my master is busy and can't be disturbed right now")

Comment: How about The Predator's slide to unlock wrist gadget which doubles as a bomb?

Comment: @Clockwork That's 1987, well after the 1960 cut-off given.  If we go that far afield, Gibson has something very fondleslab-like in *Count Zero* (1986).

Comment: Fred Pohl's mid-60's short story "The Creature from Cleveland Depths" is starting to look more prophetic.  I look forward to the cell phones flying away to a planet of their own.

Comment: Creature from the Cleveland Depths is a great story but it is by Leiber not Pohl

Comment: https://youtu.be/dmmxVA5xhuo 1980s touch screen art - just something that may be of interest to the readers

Comment: It is interesting how none of the answers include any descriptions of "computing power" in portable devices. I realize I did not specifically mention this in the OP, and it could probably be it's own question. But it is curious that in my mind, the communication features are tied to computing power (specifically *digital* computing power). But these early portrayals seem to assume that they are sophisticated analog devices.

Comment: @DavidW It's interesting that Gibson's 1984 novel Neuromancer (which takes place around 2035 according to the author) predicts the Internet (or "cyberspace") but no cell phones!

Comment: I remember when cell phones, in the form of flip phones (not the modern touchscreen/video/etc), were first becoming A Thing, and I remember saying "In 1966, we though Captain Kirk's communicator was a nifty thing. In 1993, we were roundly cursing Nextel for their push-to-talk feature"

Comment: So, a portable, wirelessly networked interaction and display device. Why would you refer to such a thing as a "telephone"?

Comment: Not a sci-fi story, but certainly science fiction at the time - Punch magazine in 1906, predicting a "wireless telegraph" which could be used for messaging or to retrieve racing results... https://relevantmagazine.com/culture/1906-cartoon-predicted-smart-phone/

Comment: Wow @Paul, that cartoon certainly nailed some common uses of our phones. The woman is sexting and the guy is gambling.

Comment: Whats interesting is that in many old science fiction, is that many of the the futuristic devices already existed, but were not mainstream.  For example, the first video phones actually existed in the 1930s.  They weren commercialized in the 60s and 70s, but never took off.

Comment: @RobertF *"Gibson's 1984 novel Neuromancer...predicts the Internet"* And only 7 years after it was [created](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Internet#1973%E2%80%931989:_Merging_the_networks_and_creating_the_Internet). :-)

Comment: Gibson's Internet is more like the Metaverse or the Matrix.  You jack in a virtual reality.  It is not TCP, FTP and the like.

Comment: The most difficult criteria is probably the "high-resolution touch screen" element.  It requires more insight to imagine how the device could realistically be used than to imagine what you want the device to do.

Comment: Mobile phones were predicted, but mobile computer/camera/video/telephone/etc. was not. Even modern stories didn't predict what would come out of the advent of the smartphone. Fiction mostly put all of those capabilities in different devices - pads and communicators in ST for instance. Even the crazy supertech stories never imagined what we would achieve. Cool isn't it?

Comment: See also: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/93979/2352

Comment: I always thought that the canonical idea was that iPhones were the realization of tricorders. But apparently tricorders didn't communicate, let alone per video. So being hand-held and "smart" are the main things in common.

Comment: And as a general notion: We all operate with the greatest nonchalance tech that was James Bond issue only two generations ago (e.g. tiny cameras and recording devices, encrypted communication, instant access to all human knowledge). (Oh, and what do we do with it? Watch porn.)

Comment: @GEdgar - Thanks for that link. There are some good answers over there that aren't here.

Comment: The list of requirements 1-4 boils down to "portable videophone", except for point 3, the touchscreen, the use of which suggests something more than a videophone but from the list it isn't clear what.

Answer (score 32):

The Joymaker from Pohl's 1966 "Age of the Pussyfoot" comes remarkably close.

This [article](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=1026) elaborates:

> The principle of it was clear enough. It was a remote input-output
> station for a shared-time computer program, with certain attachments
> that functioned as pocket flask, first-aid kit, cosmetics bag, and so
> on. It looked something like a mace or a jester's scepter.
>
> The remote-access computer transponder called the "joymaker" is your
> most valuable single possession in your new life. If you can imagine a
> combination of telephone, credit card, alarm clock, pocket bar,
> reference library, and full-time secretary, you will have sketched
> some of the functions provided by your joymaker.
>
> Essentially, it is a transponder connecting you with the central
> computing facilities of the city in which you reside on a shared-time,
> self-programming basis. "Shared-time" means that many other joymakers
> use the same central computer - in Shoggo, something like ten million
> of them. If you go to another city your joymaker will continue to
> serve you, but it must be reset to a new frequency and pulse-code.
> This will be done automatically when you travel by public
> transportation. However, if you use private means, or if for any
> reason you spend any time in the agricultural areas, you must notify
> the joymaker of your intentions.

Voice-mail includes a summary of messages and tactile and olfactory sensations:

> "Man Forrester, the personal callers are as follows:
>
> ...Adne Bensen: female, Universalist, Arcadian-Trimmer, twenty-three
> declared, five feet seven inches, experiencer-homeswoman, no business
> stated. Her kiss follows."
>
> Forrester did not know what to expect but was pleasantly ready for
> anything.
>
> What he got was indeed a kiss. It was disconcerting. No kissing lips
> were visible. There was a hint of perfumed breath, then a pressure on
> the lips - warm and soft, moist and sweet.
>
> Startled, he touched his mouth. "How the devil did you do that?" he
> shouted.
>
> "Sensory stimulation through the tactile net, Man Forrester..."

Comment: Other than "pocket flask" (has nobody rectified this by producing a case that also holds a tipple?) and the "sensory stimulation" (Dear LORD, _please_ do not let that come true!!!) this sounds pretty spot on!

Comment: This is a pretty good match. It didn't imagine that there would be computing power in the portable device, but most of the *features* are there, with the notable exception of a video display.

Comment: What's also remarkable is that is actually pretty close to an actual _cell phone_ - mobile phones and computers weren't that rare in sci-fi, but most often they worked as dedicated devices or walkie-talkies; this actually connects two callers through a (computerized, of course) switching board in a networked system rather than directly. Not surprised it comes from Pohl, though - highly advanced computer systems are pretty common in his works!

Comment: @egeorge In place of video display, we have touch and scent - features that still don't exist, and likely won't for long time due to lack of demand/feasibility.  (If you can kiss someone through the phone, can you also punch them in the face?  If you can transmit perfumed breath, can you also transmit raw sewage smell?  Probably just as well if these never happen.)

Comment: If you could punch someone in the face through the phone, telemarketing would disappear overnight.

Comment: @egeorge - a utopia!

Comment: @egeorge no they would just find a way to automate it without the face punching, or tell telemarketers to wear face masks before calling.  There will always be telemarketers and spam.  You can never stop the spam!

Comment: The touch and *especially* the olfactory stimulation is something that we wouldn't want, at least not on by default.  It reminds me of early depiction of video phones being used all over the place because they seem cool.  Now we all carry a video phone in our pocket and we mostly use it to *text* people.  Turns out cool features may not be desirable or worthwhile features.  Still other then that and their not realizing the cell phone would be mostly an independent computer only using the internet for appropriate features this is still shockingly close.

Comment: @egeorge No it would be far worse. Untraceable telemarketers from a foreign country would punch old people in the face until they handed over their bank accounts.

Comment: Hate to burst the touch bubble but phone connected bluetooth sex toys with remote partner support are a thing!

Comment: I agree, @dsollen, that all cool features aren't desirable. I'd love to be able to ask, "House, where is my son", and hear "He snuck out his bedroom window 15 minutes ago." However, I do _NOT_ want the government to ask, "Where is FreeMan?" and get a reasonable answer...

Comment: @Secretsquirrel yes, but at least you kind of have to 'sign in' to that thing, it's definitely not an 'on by default' feature.  As I understand it the Chasity cages - not googling at work to find out if that is right term -  come with a physical key incase someone's phone stops working or the get hacked and unfortunate situations result.  Don't ask me how I know that, even I'm not sure how I know that.  I'm totally not wearing any bluetooth  devices right now, and you can't prove otherwise!  DON'T JUDGE ME!  Now if you'll excuse me my crotch is vibrating which means I have to answer a call.

Comment: @FreeMan I assume FreeMan is either killing combine soldiers or hanging out with Alyx.  Though the government had better hunt him down because he owes me a half life 3 game and really needs to get to work on that!.

Comment: To me that seems as likely as (someone famous's) conclusion that a Star Trek communicator is very like a mobile phone.

Comment: @egeorge - "_If you could punch someone in the face through the phone, telemarketing would disappear overnight_" - They might give you punching rights only after you'd spent so much, and even then they might only allow you to punch those whom their programs had determined would be more likely to buy stuff if they felt a bunch of fives landing in their chops.

Answer (score 25):

This answer is based on my answer to the old question [What sci-fi work introduced handheld wireless communicators?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/196414/what-sci-fi-work-introduced-handheld-wireless-communicators). A pocket telephone from 1915 and a pocket videophone from 1930, no mention of touchscreens.

**1915: a wireless pocket telephone without video.**

["John Jones's Dollar"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57490), a short story by [Harry Stephen Keeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Stephen_Keeler); first published in the August, 1915 issue of [*The Black Cat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Cat_(US_magazine)), a scan of which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/TheBlackCatV20no03191412/The%20Black%20Cat%20v20no11%20%281915-08%2C-ifc%2C-1p%20ad%2C-contents%29#page/n45/mode/1up); the text of the story is also available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/26867). In the excerpt below, a professor is teaching a kind of Zoom class:

> "B262H72476Male, you are late to class again. What excuse have you to offer today?"
>
> From the hollow cylinder emanated a shrill voice, while the lips of the picture on the glass square moved in unison with the words:
>
> "Professor, you will perceive by consulting your class book, that I have recently taken up my residence near the North Pole. For some reason, wireless communication between the Central Energy Station and all points north of 89 degrees was cut off a while ago, on account of which fact I could not appear in the Visaphone. Hence—"
>
> "Enough, sir," roared the professor. "Always ready with an excuse, B262H72476Male. I shall immediately investigate your tale."
>
> **From his coat pocket, the professor withdrew an instrument which, although supplied with an earpiece and a mouthpiece, had no wires whatever attached. Raising it to his lips, he spoke:**
>
> "Hello. Central Energy Station, please." A pause ensued. "Central Energy Station? This is the professor of history at the University of Terra, speaking. One of my students informs me that the North Pole region was out of communication with the Visaphone System this morning. Is that statement true? I would—"
>
> A voice, apparently from nowhere, spoke into the professor's ear. "Quite true, Professor. A train of our ether waves accidently fell into parallelism with a train of waves from the Venus Substation. By the most peculiar mischance, the two trains happened to be displaced, with reference to each other, one half of a wave length, with the unfortunate result that the negative points of one coincided with the positive points of maximum amplitude of the other. Hence the two wave trains nullified each other and communication ceased for one hundred and eighty-five seconds—until the earth had revolved far enough to throw them out of parallelism."
>
> "Ah! Thank you," replied the professor. He dropped his instrument into his coat pocket and gazed in the direction of the glass square whose image had so aroused his ire. "I apologize, B262H72476Male, for my suspicions as to your veracity—but I had in mind several former experiences." He shook a warning forefinger. "I will now resume my talk."

**1930: a wireless pocket videophone.**

["Mr. Murphy of New York"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58808), a short story by [Thomas McMorrow](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?13693); first published in the March 22, 1930 issue of [*The Saturday Evening Post*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saturday_Evening_Post), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/sim_saturday-evening-post_1930-03-22_202_38/page/14/mode/2up).

> "Now, gentlemen, please," breathed Mr. Bligh. "Do remember that I'm a thousand miles from home and haven't had any lunch yet. Well, I shall have to call up." He took out his pocketell. "Are you there? Billy calling . . . Hello, Molly! I just called you to say that I can't possibly get home— What's that, sweetheart? . . . Oh, no, no. . . . But I say that I am not! I am in New York in a conference. . . . Yes, business. . . . Why don't I— Now, Molly, how can you ask me to be so rude? . . . Oh, very well, my dear, in a moment." He turned to us, coloring, and said, "Will you permit?" We were married men ourselves; we smiled and got to our feet and bowed to his lady when she appeared; her eyes swept us vigilantly. "I'm sorry this had to happen, gentlemen," said Mr. Bligh, blanking her. "May we proceed now with our affair?"

Comment: Although good luck getting a utility company's support desk to confirm an outage today.

Comment: Puget Sound Energy (Seattle area) gives live updates on outages, and can text you for changes. It's quite nice. https://www.pse.com/outage/outage-map

Comment: Duke Energy will confirm they do or don't have an active outage (and accept a report in  the latter case) on their "800-POWER-ON" reporting line as well.  They even give "underpromise" estimates for power restoration, once they've determined the cause of the outage.

Answer (score 19):

I offer this from 1897:

> There is no doubt that the day will come, maybe when you and I are forgotten, when copper wires, gutta-percha coverings, and iron sheathings will be relegated to the Museum of Antiquities.
>
> Then, when a person wants to telegraph to a friend, he knows not where, he will call an electromagnetic voice, which will be heard loud by him who has the electromagnetic ear but will be silent to everyone else.
>
> "He will call 'Where are you?' and the reply will come 'I am at the bottom of the coal-mine' or 'Crossing the Andes' or 'In the middle of the Pacific'; or perhaps no reply will come at all, and he may then conclude that his friend is dead.

Professor W. E. Ayrton speaking at a lecture at the Imperial Institute.

Comment: A lecture, is it? Not a work of fiction then?

Comment: OP didn't explicitly say that the portrayal had to be in a work of fiction. However that's one reason why I offered two distinct answers.

Comment: I figured by posting the question to this site he's implicitly asking about works of science fiction and fantasy. Otherwise, I think there is a stack exchange site for history of science and technology.

Comment: @user14111 Surely to Prof. Ayrton, it _was_ a fantasy. He just happened to speak of it rather than write a story that got published about it

Comment: Man, imagine if every time a call (or text) went unanswered, we jumped to the conclusion that the person is dead, as opposed to how it actually is, where we only jump to that conclusion sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

As I remember, in Arthur C. Clarke's *Profiles of the Future* (1962) there is mention of future personal pocket computers.  I think I remember Clarke describing them as connected to other computers, and performing many of the functions of [Jeeves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeeves) and [Robby the Robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robby_the_Robot).

Comment: Clarke also showed us something like a kindle in [ImperialEarth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Earth), but that had to be synced by wire to a computer. That was also 1975. I am sure there are things earlier.

Comment: Isn't the question asking about works of fiction? Are nonfiction essays even on topic here?

Answer (score 3):

I offer this from 1909:

> But it was fully fifteen seconds before the round plate that she held in her hands began to glow. A faint blue light shot across it, darkening to purple, and presently she could see the image of her son, who lived on the other side of the earth, and he could see her.
>
> … She could not be sure, for the Machine did not transmit nuances of expression. It only gave a general idea of people - an idea that was good enough for all practical purposes, Vashti thought. The imponderable bloom, declared by a discredited philosophy to be the actual essence of intercourse, was rightly ignored by the Machine, just as the imponderable bloom of the grape was ignored by the manufacturers of artificial fruit. Something 'good enough' had long since been accepted by our race.

The Machine Stops by E. M. Forster.

Comment: A videophone but I doubt that it was wireless. Why would it be, when people hardly ever left their rooms? And Vashti had to roll her chair to the other side of the room to answer the phone.

Comment: I don't recall that the book explicitly said it was tethered. I think it did, however, imply that the medical equipment which was used shortly after was tethered. My suspicion is that the intent was to emphasise how unfit and debilitated people were: her son later gauged his strength by holing out a cushion. However that's one reason why I offered two distinct answers.

Answer (score 1):

This one certainly deserves to be mentioned here.  I am always amazed when I see it.

In 1947 Roger Barjavel, French journalist and writer, wrote an essay from which a short movie was produced, "La Télévision, œil de demain" ("Television, the eye of tomorrow"), predicting what the future would look like.

He extrapolated that the number of TV channels would grow exponentially to the point that each person could follow his own personal program and it would be used for the most mundane tasks.  It would be be used for video calls, as a travel guide, for weather forecasts, or spy on your spouse.  Mobile TVs would be used to watch the latest soap, get updates on fashion, check sports results or even do crosswords.

You can see an extract in the following clip (in French, sorry!) https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/w16H-3lpoyU . At 6:00, it shows how mobile devices would be used.  At 6:30 the off-screen voice comments "Our roads would present a very strange sight indeed".  I let you judge on that.

OK, it is not a mobile phone, it is not a computer, it is a TV but it predicts quite accurately how ubiquitous communication affects everyday's life.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  While interesting, this postdates several of the other answers here, so it's not really a good answer.

Comment: I am sorry you don't like this post.  It is not the earliest mention of a mobile communication device, but certainly one that got it right.

Answer (score 0):

And this Nikola Tesla quote from 1926 (later than some of the others here but detailed and very prescient):

> When wireless is perfectly applied the whole earth will be converted into a huge brain, which in fact it is, all things being particles of a real and rhythmic whole. We shall be able to communicate with one another instantly, irrespective of distance. Not only this, but through television and telephony we shall see and hear one another as perfectly as though we were face to face, despite intervening distances of thousands of miles; and the instruments through which we shall be able to do his will be amazingly simple compared with our present telephone. A man will be able to carry one in his vest pocket.
>
> [Source](https://bigthink.com/words-of-wisdom/nikola-tesla-2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer has to be @user14111 with the story from 1915.

I researched this briefly because I remembered Heinlein had pocket phones in several of his stories, and found this article:

http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=595

This article also lists that 1915 story as the first example, but does cite Heinlein imagining a pocket phone in a story published in 1941.